# Set Windows XP desktop background with group policy

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, group-policy

I need to set a specific desktop background picture to a number of Windows XP machines.

Is it possible to use some group policy for this or must I do it one by one?

Comment: +1 due to good question. This is something that should be simple but is hard to find anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use "UserConfig\AdmTempl\Desktop\Active Desktop\Desktop Wallpaper" with a JPG or BMP in your group policies.

-Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. Will this work if Active Desktop is disabled?

Comment: I'm not sure... I don't think that there is any other way to do this though.  I have looked at many places on the internet for that information with no luck. I would just recommend try and posting back the results. Sorry for the lack of information. The most helpful site I have found on this topic is http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/33414555/set-wallpaper-through-group-policy.aspx. They seem to want exactly what you want.

Comment: I'd have suggested a registry key that affects all users, but this works just as well.